# Cypress - I can't access to variable

Tags: typescript, variables, cypress

I can't access to variables contactName and message2Send, although they are global variables they are just working with a limited scope, how can I do to use it in other tests.

Thank you in advance!

```
describe('Inbox', () => {
  let contactName
  let message2Send

  context('Desktop viewport', () => {
    it('Creates a thread if none exists: necessary to all the following tests', () => {
      let newContact = false
      cy.defaultLogin()
      cy.get('body').then(($el) => {
        if ($el.find('[data-cy=inbox-empty-thread]').length > 0) {
          newContact = true
          contactName = faker.name.findName()
          message2Send = faker.lorem.sentence()
        } else {
          cy.get('[data-cy=inbox-thread-0]').find('[data-cy=inbox-thread-name]').then(($elem) => {
            contactName = $elem.text()
            cy.log(contactName)
          })
          cy.get('[data-cy=inbox-thread-0]').find('[data-cy=inbox-thread-message]').then(($elem) => {
            message2Send = $elem.text()
            cy.log(message2Send)
          })
        }
      })
      cy.log(contactName, message2Send)
      cy.createThread(contactName, message2Send, newContact)
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```js
describe('Inbox', () => {
  let contactName
  let message2Send

  context('Desktop viewport', () => {
    it('Creates a thread if none exists: necessary to all the following tests', () => {
      let newContact = false
      cy.defaultLogin()
      cy.get('body').then(($el) => {
        if ($el.find('[data-cy=inbox-empty-thread]').length > 0) {
          newContact = true
          contactName = faker.name.findName()
          message2Send = faker.lorem.sentence()
        } else {
          cy.get('[data-cy=inbox-thread-0]').find('[data-cy=inbox-thread-name]').then(($elem) => {
            contactName = $elem.text()
            cy.log(contactName)
          })
          cy.get('[data-cy=inbox-thread-0]').find('[data-cy=inbox-thread-message]').then(($elem) => {
            message2Send = $elem.text()
            cy.log(message2Send)
          })
        }
      })
      cy.then(() => {
        cy.log(contactName, message2Send)
        cy.createThread(contactName, message2Send, newContact)
      })
    })
```

Please notice the `then` callback when accessing the variables.
[Cypress commands are asynchronous](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/introduction-to-cypress#Commands-Are-Asynchronous) and the variables are not yet initialized when accessed without a `then` callback.

You can also move the assignment into a `before`/`beforeEach` hook and use the variables directly in any of your `it` tests